# Two Page Curl Effect in iPad

Tags: ios, uianimation

I am using the Leaves project to move from one pdf page to another it is working fine. Now the page curl is from left to right and from right to left like a note book. Now the effect was to turn a single page but i want to turn the two pages .one page has to display in left side and another page has to display in right side.

Comment: Leaves does not support this behavior.  Judging by its last refresh date I doubt it ever will.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `UIPageViewController`, unless you're trying to support iOS 4.  `UIPageViewController` supports having the spine in the middle of the screen so you can see two pages at once.  I don't know if Leaves is relevant anymore since there's a better solution built right into iOS 5 and up.

Comment: can u pls provide a tutorial that opens the pdf file using UIPageViewController

Comment: use this http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/06/rendering-pdf-is-easier-than-you-thought/ and just work it into the page view controllers. read the UIPageViewController documentation.